# Cypress не видит элементы у сайта на JSP

Tags: jsp, test-automation

Есть ресурс на технологии jsp. Нужно написать на него автотесты на Cypress. Однао после авторизации Cypress не видит новые элементы на странице.
При этом, вне действий Cypress ресурс отображается нормально, URL определяется корректно.

Что я упустил и как сделать чтобы элементы находились корректно?

[image: Так выглядит экран на отдельных действиях]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема происходит из-за тэга `<iframe>`
Здесь подробно объясняется как обойти это:
https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/